# How to simulate a close() in facebox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebox

I am using facebox popup in one of my pages. I am having a button in the popup dialog. When I click that button the facebox popup should close (the same way it closes when we press outside the popup). How to do that?

Also, I am doing some Ajax stuff when that button is being pressed so I cannot override the onClick event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('#button-id').click($.facebox.close);
});
```

as long as you aren't actually setting event handlers through onclick, adding handlers won't override existing ones.

Comment: I dont know where to put this code. :(. Sorry, I am new to JQuery.. These $ look a bit alien to me..  Can you plz explain what is happenin here ?

Comment: a function inside $() basically runs as soon as the dom is fully loaded. so you could put that whole block inside a script tag in the header.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, i got it working by putting jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox')

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='jQuery("#facebox_overlay").click();'>close</a>
```

here's an onclick version hack

Answer (score 4):

For close the facbox in code, trigger:

```
jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem closing facebox, and was thay the dark overlay that appeared when opened it, didn´t close.

the solution I used was this one:

```
  $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
    $('#back').hide();
  })
```

back is the id of the dark overlay

Hope this is usefull

Greetings from Spain